# Facebook Audience Network not displaying Ad icon

Tags: ios, facebook-audience-network

Icon never appears, other elements displayed correctly. Sample code:

```
private lazy var adIconView: FBMediaView = {
  var iconView = FBMediaView()
  return iconView
}()


let clickableViews = [adIconView, adTitleLabel, adBodyLabel, adSocialContextLabel, adActionButton]
nativeAd?.registerView(forInteraction: contentView,
                       mediaView: adCoverMediaView,
                       iconView: adIconView,
                       viewController: nil,
                       clickableViews: clickableViews)

nativeAd?.delegate = self
```

FB sample does not show icon too https://github.com/fbsamples/audience-network/tree/master/samples/ios/AdUnitsSample

Answer (score 0):

Facebook Audience sdk has deprecated class FBAdIconView which work normally now. Hope it will be fixed soon